# Did Kenobi use the dark side against Maul in Episode I (Phantom Menace)?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, obi-wan-kenobi

@3:05 when Jinn dies Kenobi screams "No" and I can't really tell his emotion from his facial expression (maybe anger or fear?).  When he senses the gates are about to open he seems ansy to attack (quite the contrast to Jinn's calm demeanor @2:10-2:30).  When Kenobi fights Maul (**moment**:refers to this time interval) @3:25-@4:10 he seemed to be on the offensive.  During that **moment** was Kenobi using the dark side (did he want revenge/was angry for Jinn's death) or was he calm and using the light?

In The Clone Wars series, @1:35 Maul makes Kenobi angry (instead of remaining calm) as if to confirm that Kenobi was using the dark side for that **moment** (Kenobi is angry when he thinks about Jinn's death).

The closest answer I found was on question: [Why can Darth Maul successfully combat Qui-gon and Obi-Wan simultaneously, but not easily defeat them individually?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89307/why-can-darth-maul-successfully-combat-qui-gon-and-obi-wan-simultaneously-but-s)
where Richard quoted Brook's novelization of Phantom Menace: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_%28novel%29

> Eyes fixed on the Sith Lord, Obi-Wan Kenobi went deep inside himself,
>   connecting with the Force he had worked so hard to understand. Calming
>   himself, stilling the trembling of his heart, and banishing his anger
>   and fear, he called upon the last of his reserves. With clarity of
>   purpose and strength of heart, he launched himself away from the side
>   of the pit and catapulted back toward its lip. Imbued with the power
>   of the Force, he cleared the rim easily, somersaulting behind the Sith
>   Lord in a single smooth, powerful motion. Even as he landed, he was
>   drawing Qui-Gon Jinn’s fallen lightsaber to his outstretched hand.
>
> Darth Maul whirled to confront him, shock and rage twisting his red
>   and black face. But before he could act to save himself, Qui-Gon’s
>   lightsaber slashed through his chest, burning him with killing fire.
>   The stricken Sith Lord howled in pain and disbelief.

This tells me after the **moment** (@4:25-4:45 of 1st video) Kenobi's finishing blow (or last blow of this duel not necessarily killing blow) was augmented with the light side.

However during that **moment** (@3:25-4:10 of 1st video) was Kenobi with the light or dark?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- **It doesn't say explicitly in canon that he used the Dark Side**
- but there's definitely a confirmation in the novelization that he was running on negative emotions.

Given the fact that ROTJ novelization explicitly acknowledged that Luke was accessing the Dark Side when fighting Vader, I would tentatively conclude that Obi-Wan **likely was not**, or the TPM novelization would have been more explicit about it. **Bit he seemingly came extremely close even so**.

> He was slumped forward and motionless when the lasers abruptly went off again, and Obi-Wan Kenobi, **seething with rage, rushed to his rescue**.

...

> Free at last of the laser wall, Obi-Wan Kenobi charged out of the service tunnel and into the chamber that housed the melting pit. Abandoning any pretense of observing even the slightest caution, **he barreled into Darth Maul with such fury that he almost knocked both of them off the ledge and into the abyss. He struck at the Sith Lord with his lightsaber as if his own safety meant nothing, lost in a red haze of rage and frustration, consumed by his grief for Qui-Gon and his failure to prevent his friend’s fall**.

...

> Eventually, the Sith Lord began to wear the young Jedi down. Bit by bit, he pressed him back, carrying the attack to him, looking to catch him off guard. Obi-Wan could sense his body weakening, and his fear of what it would mean if he, too, were to fall, began to grow.
>
> Never! he swore furiously
>
> Qui-Gon’s words came back to him. Don’t center on your fears. Concentrate on the here and now. He **struggled to do so, to contain the emotions warring within and bearing him down**. Be mindful of the living Force, my young Padawan. Be strong.
>
> Sensing his opportunity slipping away from him and his strength waning, Obi-Wan mounted a final assault. He rushed the Sith Lord with a series of side blows designed to bring the two-bladed lightsaber horizontal. Then he feinted an attack to his enemy’s left and brought his own lightsaber over and down with such force that he severed the other’s weapon.
>
> **Crying out in fury**, he cut triumphantly at the Sith Lord’s horned head, a killing blow.